# I want to isolate the IP and the port from a string in a python script

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a script which will read in information, and process it.

I have the script so that it reads in the information.

For example:

```
RawInfo[0] = "192.168.100.254:8081"
```

I want to be able to isolate the port number, and isolate the IP address, and store them in two separate variables, so the end result of my script is

```
IP_from_RawInfo = "192.168.100.254"
Port_from_rawInfo = "8081"
```

I know regex  can do this somehow but I don't really know how to use it! Can somebody give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> basis = "192.168.100.254:8081"
>>> basis.split(':')
['192.168.100.254', '8081']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even with regex it's dead easy ;p

```
>>> import re
>>> ip, other = re.split(':', s)
>>> print ip
192.168.100.254
>>> print other
8081
```

But as @zhangyangyu showed, you can simply use `.split(':')`